# Apple Remote Desktop - Safari Homepage - How to set to Home Page

Tags: safari, apple-remote-desktop

Using Apple Remote Desktop, how do I initiate Safari, to began with a preferred web site?

Example, I have 50 Mac(s) on my network, and I want each users automatically began on a specific default web site as their Safari Home Page.

Thank you so much and have a beautiful day.

Fabio

Answer (score 2):

The fastest thing that comes to my mind is to send an UNIX command to the clients with the following contents:

```
defaults write com.apple.Safari HomePage 'http://example.com'
```

This sets the Safari homepage for the user that runs the command.

I hope this helps.